# Can i transfer my Prevew signatures from a Time Machine backup drive to a new Macbook Pro? (old mac died)

Tags: time-machine, preview, signature

I would like to put the signatures I had on an old Macbook that died onto my new Macbook Pro.  I have a copy of Time Machine from my old Mac.  Can I use that to transfer Preview signatures to new Macbook Pro? Thanks.

Comment: Whatever was saved can be transferred - some sites will need password updates though like banks.